# What am I doing wrong with my movement script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm kinda new to this whole unity thing. I've been programming in C# for a while now and usually in order for something to move I'd just do a little "_playerPosition.x += 5;" but I tried that in Unity and it doesn't seem to work.
This is my current movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
Vector2 _playerPosition;
GameObject Player;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    _playerPosition = Vector2.zero;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        _playerPosition.y += 5f; 
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        _playerPosition.y -= 5f;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
        _playerPosition.x += 5f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
        _playerPosition.x -= 5f;
    }
    Player.transform.position = _playerPosition;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `_playerPosition`?

Comment: I googled [`GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) and it only returns `true` for one single tick. This method tells you if the user *pressed* the button just then, not if they are *pressing* it. The docs indicate you probably want to use [`GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) instead: "Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name. Think auto fire."

Comment: @CNuts _playerPosition is a Vector2.

Comment: @Quantic I just switched them out and it did nothing. I'm not getting any error as well.

Comment: Could you show the full script?

Comment: @CNuts public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
 Vector2 _playerPosition;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  _playerPosition = Vector2.zero;
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 GameObject Player;
 void Update () {
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
   _playerPosition.y += 5f; 
  }

  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
   _playerPosition.y -= 5f;
  }

  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
   _playerPosition.x += 5f;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
   _playerPosition.x -= 5f;
  }
  Player.transform.position = _playerPosition;
 }
}

Comment: Edit your question and add the code to it, don't put it as a comment. And is that script on your player?

Comment: I believe the PlayerMovement is already a class of the object and so doesn't need the whole player in there instead put `this.transform.position` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply move your player that the script is attached too

```
public float speed = 5f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
       transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

[Similar question on Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/667641/how-do-i-move-my-2d-object-using-arrow-keys-also-h.html)

You can change the value of `speed` for whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks! It works but it's really choppy at times. It might be frame rate, any way to fix that?

Comment: @LiamEarle You're welcome :) what do you mean by _choppy_?

Comment: Almost like I'm getting bad FPS. Like frameskip.

Comment: Good example of dealing with _Time and framerate differences across devices look at about 35 minutes into this tutorial on [shaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0uJ4sZelio)

Comment: @LiamEarle it's gonna be hard to tell without seeing a video and you might consider asking a new question with that problem.

Comment: @CNuts do you have steam or some messaging service? You seem to be very helpful.

Comment: @LiamEarle I don't have one at the moment for SO, but I'm sure you'll get answers to your questions here. There's people with much more knowledge than me on SO. Unity has great tutorials if you wanna learn more.

Comment: @LiamEarle as you stated this got your code working, so you should upvote and select answer. As to your timing issues that is another problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

`_playerPosition` is a variable that contains Vector2 as you mentioned in comment. Make sure you set new position using that variable after all calculations.

## Edit

Check that out. Remember to assign your Player object from scene into script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector2 _playerPosition;
    public GameObject Player; // assign your player prefab

    void Start () {
        _playerPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            _playerPosition.y += 5f; 
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            _playerPosition.y -= 5f;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            _playerPosition.x += 5f;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            _playerPosition.x -= 5f;
        }
        
        Player.transform.position = _playerPosition;
    }

}
```

Comment: I get an error that says "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/PlayerMovement.cs:29)"

Comment: Googled what is on line 29 in your PlayerMovement script but even Google has no idea what is there.... Show me your code, make edit to your question.

Comment: CNuts works really well. But it's a bit choppy it might be frame rate anyway to fix that?

Comment: Then it's up to you to get it right as you want. I don't know how is it working for you, can't see or even test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within your update

```
void Update(){
    int d = 0;
    int speed = 5;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
       d=90; 
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
        d = 270;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
        d = 0;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
        d=180;
    }
    this.transform.position += new Vector3((int)(speed * Mathf.Sin(d * Mathf.Deg2Rad)), 0, (int)(speed * Mathf.Cos(d * Mathf.Deg2Rad)));
}
```

Rather this is for a 3d but can just be transfered to 2d

Comment: the movement is just really jumpy now.

Comment: well this was my movement code for a 3d object and Vector3 is based on radian not degrees. There could be a difference for that in dealing with Vector2

Comment: Yeah I switched out the the Vector3 to Vector2

Comment: CNuts works really well. But it's a bit choppy it might be frame rate anyway to fix that?

Comment: @LiamEarle Talking about jumpy makes me think of something along CNuts' answer. Here are some tutorial links that deal with the timing use for better portability across devices [link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwuPiaFU37w) and look at about 35 minutes in here [shaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0uJ4sZelio)